# Creating a list of "quadros"

Tags: table-of-contents, captions, longtable

I'm trying to create a new list of contents in my document with the title "Lista de Quadros". To create these "quadros" i had to use the package \longtable, so the challenge that i'm facing is to change the captions of the longtables (transform "tables" into "quadros") and then create this new list. Moreover, I've to maintain the list of tables apart of the "Lista de Quadros" (they are two different lists)

I'm new to Latex and any kind of help would be very helpful.

Thank you

Comment: Related: [Trying to use longtable to make it span multiple pages but can't control to which list it goes to](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/548021/79060)

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6478/